# How do I decline observed call with CallKit?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, callkit

I'm completely new to Swift programming and I don't know how to make this work.
Basically I have and iOS app which observes incoming phone calls and declines it automatically if the caller number is equal to a user defined number to decline, without showing user any notification (this app is only for my private use).

Currently I have this code which observes incoming call. It works like a charm but I don't know how to make it decline the call (for now all phone numbers).

```
import CallKit

class CallTest: NSObject, CXCallObserverDelegate, ObservableObject {
    @Published var incomingCallNumber: String?
    
    let callObserver = CXCallObserver()

    override init() {
        super.init()

        callObserver.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
    }
    
    func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall) {
        if (call.isOutgoing == false && call.hasConnected == false) {
            print("Incoming call")
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to decline incoming call like this.

```
import CallKit

class CallTest: NSObject, CXCallObserverDelegate, ObservableObject {
    @Published var incomingCallNumber: String?
    
    let callObserver = CXCallObserver()

    override init() {
        super.init()

        callObserver.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
    }
    
    func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall) {
        if (call.isOutgoing == false && call.hasConnected == false) {
            print("Incoming call")
let callController = CXCallController()
            let endCallAction = CXEndCallAction(call: call.uuid)
            let transaction = CXTransaction(action: endCallAction)

            callController.request(transaction) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error declining call: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Call declined successfully")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I keep getting error:

> Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=2 "(null)"

Which means 'unknownCallProvider', but I don't know how to set provider for this.

Comment: This is the wrong approach.  You can use a CallKit Directory extension and provide a blocklist.  iOS will then take care of declining the call for you

Comment: @Paulw11 I know but that's not I'm trying to do. Basically I want specific number to be declined and to app send request to the server. As I wrote this is for private use and specific case. But for now I just want to know how to decline any caller.

Comment: You can't.  An app can't see the details of an incoming number and it can't decline a call. Private app or otherwise, it just isn't something apps can do.

Comment: @Paulw11 So if I understand, app like this (verizon.com/solutions-and-services/call-filter) which automatically decline potential spam call. Does not verifies caller number with their database and then decline it, but they fill your blocklist from their database ?

Comment: They are a carrier, so they can get the calling number from their network.  They can fill the on-device block list from their database but they can also match the incoming number against their database on their server in order to provide the list of calls they blocked.

Comment: @Paulw11 So if I understand there is no way for me to compare incoming number with number I want to be declined and verify as call which send server request. Besides becoming an carrier ? Ehh.. that's ruined all of my plans. As apple user I never thought  that I will have to make it on android. What about SMS/Call reporting extension ? Even in settings apple write that '..the developer will receive information about the call, such as the caller's number..'

Comment: Correct.  It is a privacy issue.  An unwanted communication extension is different.   The user makes a decision to send a specific number to an unwanted communication extension.  The extension does not receive details of all incoming calls/sms

Comment: @Paulw11 If I'm not wrong, with extension and some concessions I can achieve what I'm looking for. Am I wrong ? And I should start looking for android device for tests ?

Comment: You can manually report a number each time via an unwanted communication extension, but you can't automatically block the call and report it.